# Prove that $f$ is a linear combination of $\delta^{(k)}$ for $k=0, 1\ldots, n-1$.

Tags: distribution-theory, dirac-delta

Let $f$ is a tempered distribution such that $x^nf =0$ for an integer $n$. Prove that $f$ is a linear combination of $\delta^{(k)}$ for $k=0, 1\ldots, n-1$.

$\delta$ is Dirac delta function.

Please help me. I have no idea.

Comment: The support of $f$ is the singleton $\{0\}$ and every distribution with this support is a linear combination of derivatives of the Dirac distribution. This is a standard result proved in every treatment of distribution theory, I would recommend Rudin's *Functional Analysis* or Hörmander's *The Analysis of Linear Partial Differential Operators I*.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [A distribution as a linear combination of Dirac delta and its derivatives](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2793021/a-distribution-as-a-linear-combination-of-dirac-delta-and-its-derivatives) (I have found this reference almost at once using the formula searching tool https://approach0.xyz/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $\phi \in \mathcal S(\mathbb R)$ and $P = \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \frac{\phi^{(k)}(0)}{k!} x^k$ its Taylor polynomial with degree $k-1$ around $0$.

Then, there is a $\mathcal C^{+\infty}$ function $\psi$ such that [[see here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1606068)]:
$$\phi = P + x^n \psi$$

Let $\chi$ be a smooth compactly supported function that is $1$ on a neighborhood of $0$. Then, $\chi P$ and $\chi x^n \psi \in \mathcal S(\mathbb R)$.

Therefore :
\begin{align}
\langle f,\phi\rangle &= \langle f , \chi \phi\rangle \\
&= \langle f, \chi P\rangle +\langle x^n f, \psi\rangle \\
&= \langle f,\chi P\rangle
\end{align}

Therefore $\langle f,\phi\rangle$ only depends (linearly) on $\phi(0), \phi^{(1)}(0),\ldots, \phi^{(n-1)}(0)$, ie $f$ is a linear combination of $\delta_0,\delta^{(1)}_0,\ldots,\delta_0^{(n-1)}$